# Karate - Disable hook for called feature using execution Hook

Tags: karate

I am using Execution hook interface in karate for customised report, here i am using called feature in my scenario.
Since my scenario contain called feature, while running it is coming to BeforeScenario Part for second time , is there any way to disable hooks for called feature.

Because called feature is one step in my scenario , how can we make as separate scenario condition.

public class CustomHook  implements ExecutionHook {

```
@Override
public boolean beforeScenario(Scenario scenario, ScenarioContext context) {
    boolean skip =false;
    String currentTestcase=scenario.getName();
    System.out.println(currentTestcase);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old version of Karate which is no longer supported. Many teams have followed the migration guide and are far ahead: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#hooks

And you can easily check if this is the root scenario or not by calling `ScenarioRuntime.caller.depth` or `ScenarioRuntime.caller.isNone()`

Comment: Yes, thank you after updating we got these function. But Scenario ignore is not happening in this version when put beforesceanrio boolean value to false? could you please help me on it ?

Comment: @vimal maybe it is a bug no one has reported yet. follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue (of course the ideal thing is that you contribute code) as a workaround, throw an exception